# store field requirements before calling python function?

Tags: python, dictionary, object

I've got a huge dictionary with a lot of keys. There are certain fields I need to use to compute KPI's. Is there a way to store the required fields for the KPI's calculations and drop all the others? Ideally, I just want to do this on the read so I don't even load these fields if I am not going to use them. Some users will use these functions directly so I don't want to wrap them in a class which will have to be instantiated while others will call several KPIs all at once.

```py
data = {
  A : some values...
  .
  . 
  .
  Z : some values... 
}

def foo(dict): 
  # requires field A

def bar(dict): 
  # requires field B


kpis_to_calculate = [foo, bar]
requirements = set(requirements(foo) -> returns A, requirements(bar) -> returns B)

min_data_needed = filter(data, requirements)
```

One way I came up with to do this was to wrap the functions e.g. but this solution is ugly

```
def _foo(dict): 
  # requires field A

def _bar(dict): 
  # requires field B

foo = setattr(_foo, '__requires__', 'A')
bar = setattr(_bar, '__requires__', 'B')

kpis = [foo, bar]
requires = [requirement for requirement in func.__requires__ for func in kpis]

# only loads fields needed
load(data_src, required_fields=requires)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a decorator in such a case:

```
def requires(*requirements):
    def _decorator(f):
        f.__requires__ = requirements
        return f
    return _decorator


@requires('A')
def foo(d):
    ...

@requires('B')
def bar(d):
    ...


kpis = [foo, bar]
requirements = [req for func in kpis for req in func.__requires__]
load(data_src, required_fields=requirements)
```

Notes:

1. We do not need `setattr`, because the attribute is a constant.
2. `setattr` returns `None`, it doesn't return the original object!
3. Pay attention to the order of nested loops in list comprehensions!

Comment: You are an an angle! I tried this but I couldn't get it to work! Thank you so much!
```
def requires(*fields, **kwargs):
    def wrap(function):
        setattr(function, '__requires__', fields)
        def compute(*args, **kwargs):
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        return compute
    return wrap